# Do taxis in Frankfurt typically accept credit cards?

Tags: germany, payment-cards, taxis, frankfurt

I will be taking a taxi from outside the main airport in Frankfurt. Will I be able to use a credit card to pay for the trip?

Comment: You may want to also consider Uber -- they have [presence in Frankfurt](https://www.uber.com/cities/frankfurt) and always accept credit cards.

Comment: @mustaccio Please note that Uber is not a registered taxi service and according to German regulations might even be illegal. Uber dropped their prices today to extremely low levels to comply with federal regulations, but if this is enough remains to be seen. Many Uber drivers already left the program because they don't see the point of driving people around for the new price of € 0.35 per km (which is the highest allowed by the law and is meant to cover travel expenses like gas and wear&tear).

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Great, up-to-date, comment. It should be noted, though, that nobody is trying to hold the users of Uber responsible (which is quite likely not possible as the user cannot know, e.g., if the driver has the necessary certification) for not sticking with the law, but only Uber and their drivers. So the Uber client is probably fine. IANAL, though.

Comment: @Nate:  €0.35 per km?! Indeed, what is the point?! What were the legislators thinking? And how can they prevent workers from making money?

Comment: @Lightness According to [Ubers blog](http://blog.uber.com/MYchoiceUBERde), they set this number, not legislators. Background: A special drivers license is required for drivers of vehicles transporting passengers commercially, and the vehicles are required to undergo safety inspections more frequently than private vehicles. Uber requires neither and lowered the price to be able to claim that the "clients" are just covering expenses and no commercial passenger transport is taking place, it seems.

Comment: @arne.b: Crazy.

Comment: I have a similar query, but for Holland, specifically Amsterdam from the airport.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Then you should do some research and post a separate question here if you can't find the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [several](http://www.frankfurt-tourismus.de/cms/tourismussuite/en/tourist_information_frankfurt/parking_public_transportion/taxi_cab_velotaxi.html) [sites](http://www.taxiprices.com/taxi-fares-in-frankfurt-germany.html) [online](http://www.ihatetaxis.com/airport/FRA-Frankfurt-Airport/Frankfurt-Airport-taxi-service), most taxis will take credit cards in Frankfurt.

However, as the third link suggests, it's always worth checking with the driver first to ensure that a) they take credit cards and b) whether or not there are any fees associated with doing so:

> Always confirm with your Frankfurt Airport taxi driver if they take
>   credit or bank cards and if there are any card fees.

So short answer - probably, but check with the driver/company before you get in/book.

Answer (score 10):

As first-hand experience from someone who lives in that city...

In theory, yes, definitely. This is standard.

In practice, a lot of taxi drivers will try to find an excuse so they don't have to accept payment by card (like "Oh, but you should have asked before, I don't have that machine on me"). I only had it happen once that the driver *really* couldn't handle the payment. In all other cases, it turned out being a lame excuse, and when I said I couldn't pay otherwise, it was suddenly possible.

By the way: The pickup price is fixed at €2.80 during daytime and 3.30 during the night (22-6h), regardless of how and where you get into the taxi (slightly lower rates in other cities, usually from 2.00 to 2.20€). They don't seem to be cheating with that, at least it hasn't ever happened to me.

Also note that when *calling* a taxi, the taxameter in Germany does **not** start when you pick up the phone, but when you board the car (by contrast, in France it seems to be "normal" that they start counting when the telephone rings, so you will not rarely have upwards of 10€ on the taxameter when you enter the cab if you called it by phone).
I've had someone try to pull off that one on me twice in 10 years.

Luggage does **not** cost extra (also contrary to other countries).

Comment: _"in France it seems to be 'normal' that they start counting when the telephone rings"_ lolwut, srs?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: As far as I know, what's legal is that you are charged the fare from the nearest taxi stand (plus 2.50 pickup, so anywhere from 3.00 to 3.50€). But in practice, they'll insist you pay for them coming from the other side of the city, and you'll almost always have around 10€ on the taxameter. Hardly a way around that since they're all cheating you. As foreigner, anyway...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes... no wonder why French cab drivers are scared by Uber!

Comment: Note that no surcharge for luggage is something specific to Frankfurt, not to Germany. In Munich, for example, it's 60 Cents per piece of luggage.